# How do I model 1:N:N relationship in Dynamo DB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I have a school which has a many class/grade(1-10) and each class has many students, I need to store a student's record on a yearly basis so that I could partition better. So its basically Class->N years->N students. How do I model this problem to store this on a Dynamo DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On NoSQL, the design depends on the **Query Access Pattern (QAP)**. As you have not mentioned QAP, how you would like to retreive the data. I have assumed a typical scenario and provided the below design.

> Table : Student
>
> Partition Key : Student Id
>
> Sort Key : year
>
> Other attributes: Student name, class etc.

The year is defined as sort key because a student can study in multiple grades (1-10) during different years. For eg,

- 2010 - He/She could be on grade 5
- 2011 - He/She could be on grade 6

In case, if you would like to get all the student ids for a particular year, you can **create GSI** (Global Secondary Index) on year field.

> Partition Key for the index : year

If you have any other access pattern, please update the question. So that we can discuss the answer for that particular query access pattern (QAP).

Comment: Let me put this differently as a businessman I run multiple shops and each shop has multiple transactions on a daily basis.Each transaction contains a set of products that were ordered.

As a businessman I need to track my inventory, manage accounts/billing etc

Comment: In NoSQL, relationships doesn't matter a lot. You need to provide the access pattern i.e. how you would query the database table. Example: Query by shopkeeper or transaction or shop. This is more important than the relationship. You need to think completely different here. You need to remove the SQL design hat when you design NoSQL database. Otherwise, it wouldn't work.